# How to split array values into to separate arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array that stores lat/long together. For example:

```
@values[0] = "-0.709999984318709,60.690000003554324"
```

I am trying to separate this into two arrays, `@lat` and `@long`, based on the comma.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is the array element actually a string with a comma in the middle, or a reference to an array with 2 elements?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley its a string with a comma in it. I created it by spliting a string into an array based on spaces.

Comment: You knew that you wanted to `split`.  So try `perldoc -f split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it's better to write $values[0] to reference the array element.

The split command will help you here, assuming the comma is consistent:

```
foreach (@values) {
  my @separated = split(',', $_);
  push @lat, $separated[0];
  push @long, $separated[1];
}
```

There's a number of ways this can be done, but I've done it in a manner that should show how the arrays are handled.

Comment: thanks. this works but seems to do something odd with my loop

 print "$name: @values\n\n";

would return each area name and its coordinates, one by one.

but print "$name: @long\n\n"; 

returns all the longitudes for all of the areas, repeatedly for every name.

I think I put the code in the right place, but cant think of why this.

Comment: @whatahitson What `$name` variable are you talking about? You can't just invent new things to put into your question.

Comment: @TLP  `$name` is the name of each map that I have coordinates for. I tried to keep my question simple by only including the relevent part of my code. Is it better form to include all of the code in my script?

Comment: @whatahitson If you want recommendations on a data structure, yes.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to keep each latitude and longitude value together, in which case transforming your array into a two-dimensional array would be appropriate:

```
my @latlong = map { [ split /,/, $_, 2 ] } @values
```

I used the full notation of `split` here in order to invoke the `LIMIT` condition of 2 fields. It may not matter for this data, but it may matter if the conditions change.

The code of the `map` statement first splits each element of `@values` into two, puts the resulting list of 2 into an anonymous array `[ ... ]`, which is then inserted into the new array. The resulting array looks like this when printed with `Data::Dumper`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '-0.709999984318709',
            '60.690000003554324'
          ]
        ];
```